# JSON.parse syntax issue with a string in array structure

Tags: javascript, json

I have a simple string which is structured like this:

```
[[Home],[685,300],[800,380],[685,300],[Home]]
```

Basically its an array of co-ordinates, to create a path. The `Home` is used because this changes based on user's location on the map.

The problem i face is when i pass it from PHP to JS.

I json_encode the data and pass it across like this:

```
[{"path":"[[Home],[685,300],[800,380],[685,300],[Home]]","id":"1"}]
```

Then i create my object for it `after` i JSON.parse:

```
paths = {};
for(var i in data){     
  paths[data[i].id] = {}
  paths[data[i].id].path = data[i].path;
}
```

The problem is `data[i].path` is still just a string and not a useable array. So i tried to add a secondary JSON.parse to change the string to a useable array like this:

```
paths[data[i].id].path = JSON.parse(data[i].path);
```

But this causes:

```
 Unexpected token H
```

The `H` is obviously coming from `Home` that i put in the array, so I am wondering what i can do convert it to a useable array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string is not valid JSON. `Home` would be a javascript identifier of that name. `"Home"` is a string. The quotes are missing.

Comment: Ah damn ! I tried single quotes but didnt try double quotes xD Thanks @Jan!